# SwiftUI and Firebase: Get Info from push notifications

Tags: firebase, push-notification, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I want to receive `push notifications` from `Firebase` into my `SwiftUI`'s app.
I can see my notification and works good but I don't know how to handle action values to do something with data. I read about `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but didn't work. Do you know any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much...

[image]

[image]

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
  
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    
    print(userInfo)
    
    
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves my life:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let url = userInfo["url"] as! String
        
        print(url)
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool, man. I can't help but noticed you said that your app is still receiving push notifications. Can you point the rest of us in the right direction for developers who haven't implemented the correct steps in network administration for APNS ever since Apple stopped supporting Legacy ports 2195 and 2196?